# How to solve during use axios little problem?

Tags: laravel, vuetify.js

I'm going to get data from a database using axios.

Props was announced as follows:

```
<script>
    export default {
        props:['data'],
    }
</script>
```

```
  <v-flex xs8>
         <question
         v-for="question in questions"
         :key="question.path"
         :data=question
         ></question>
  </v-flex>
```

And During data connect router-link there were some issues.

```
<h3 class="headline mb-0">
    <router-link :to="data.path">
        {{ data.title }}
    </router-link>

    <!-- <router-link to="data.path">
         {{ data.title }}
    </router-link> -->
</h3>
<div class="class=grey--text text--darken-2"> {{ data.created_at }} </div>
```

Problem title is:

> Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "to". Expected String, Object, got Undefined

Detail:

```
found in

---> <RouterLink>
       <VCard>
         <Question> at resources/js/components/Forum/Question.vue
           <Forum> at resources/js/components/Forum/Forum.vue
             <AppHome> at resources/js/components/AppHome.vue
               <Root>
```

Answer (score 0):

It was because your prop `data` does not contain a `path` element that's why the error tells you that it was expecting `String` or `Object` but what they received was `undefined`.

Make sure you correctly passing a prop to that component and that prop `data` must contain a `path` element, like this

```
<script>
    export default {
        props:{
           data: {
               type:Object,
               default: {
                   path:'',
                   created_at: '',
               }
           }
        },
    }
</script>
```